# How to set an element focused on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I've a HTML 5 video element which on click I need to make it to be focused so I could control user keyboard triggers.

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
    var focused_vid;
    $('.videoe').click(function(){ focused_vid = this });
    $(document).keydown(function(e){ 
        if (focused_vid){
            // keyboard handler
        }
    });
});
```

Beside my video element I've a Text Box. The problem is once the video is focused It disable me to type on my Text Box and keeps triggering Key button for video handler even though I've:

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
    $(e.srcElement.className).focus();
});
```

Regards :)

Comment: The `e` in your `$(window).click` is not defined. So the callback most likely throws an error on click and even if not the the `e` would not be the click event.

Comment: @t.niese Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `event.srcElement` it's a non-standard IE property that Firefox doesn't support. Use `event.target` which is supported by all modern browsers. Try the `.blur()` method to take the `focus` away from the video. See the Snippet for example of how this could be done.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(function() {
  var focused_vid;
  $('#vid1').click(function() {
    focused_vid = this
  });
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (focused_vid) {
      console.log('focused on ' + e.target.className);
    }
  });
});

$(window).click(function(e) {

  $('#vid1').blur();
  var tgt = e.target;
  $(tgt).focus();
  console.log('focused on ' + tgt.className);

});
```

```css
/* This just to prevent the console from obscuring the demo */

input {
  display: block;
}
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper {
  margin-left:270px;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  color: blue;
  font: 400 15px/1.3 Consolas;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='inp1' class='txt' tabindex='2' placeholder="Enter this video's title">
<video id="vid1" class='vid' src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" controls tabindex='1' width='250'></video>
```

Comment: Well this worked with elements focus but still it is triggering buttons as video handler.

Comment: I forgot to remove the `tabindex` attributes. If removing them doesn't fix that behavior, could you post the event handler for the `ended` event? There might be something you overlooked and a set of fresh eyes (mine are actually bloodshot) might find something.

Answer (score 0):

It might help others too.

```
var focused_vid=null;
$(function(){
    $('.videoe').click(function(){ focused_vid = this });
    $(document).keydown(function(e){ 
        if (focused_vid){
            // keyboard handler
        }
    });
});

function notfocused(){
    focused_vid=null;
}
```

And later on we Can call `notfocused` method to remove handling keyboard buttons for video.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    $('.videoe').blur();
    var tgt = e.target;
    $(tgt).focus();
    if(tgt.className!="videoe")
        notfocused();
});
```